# JavaScript - String.newProperty vs. String.prototype.newProperty?

Tags: javascript, prototype

In the code snippet at http://jsfiddle.net/javascriptenlightenment/QvbDw/, the author augments the builtin String object constructor with 2 new properties - an array property and a function property.

I notice that for the new array property, he did this:

```
String.newArrayProperty = [];
// Q1: Why not String.prototype.newArrayProperty = []; ?
```

But for the new function property, he did this:

```
String.prototype.newFunctionProperty = function() {...};
// Q2: Why not String.newFunctionProperty = function() {...}; ?
```

What's the difference between String.newProperty and String.prototype.newProperty?

Answer (score 5):

`String.newProperty` adds a new propery to the `String` native function, but that property is in no way inherited by the strings it generates, while `String.prototype.newProperty` adds that new property to all the strings it generates, but not to the native function itself.

Answer (score 2):

`String.property` just ads the `propery` to `String` class as to an object, `String.prototype.property` adds this property to all instances of this class.

```
function F() {
}

F.p1 = function () { console.log('F.p1'); } ;
F.prototype.p2 = function () { console.log('F.prototype.p2'); } ;

F.p1(); // 'F.p1'
F.p2(); // error
new F().p1(); // error
new F().p2(); // 'F.prototype.p2'
```

Also look at:

1. [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)
2. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Answer (score 0):

A method, assigned to the prototype of `String` can be applied to all instances of String. A method assigned to the `String` constructor has to be called as a *[static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods)* method with a string as parameter. If the method is in the prototype, within it, `this` refers to the string instance.

So:

```
String.prototype.insertLineNr = function(nr){return (nr||1) + ': ' +this;};
//                                                                  ^instance
String.insertLineNo = function(str,nr){return (nr||1) + ': ' +str;};
var str = 'Some line to be numbered';
//apply to instance
console.log(str.insertLineNr(5);        //=> '5: Some line to be numbered'
//can't apply direct String method to instance 
console.log(str.insertLineNo(str,5));   //=> TypeError
//Run String method 
console.log(String.insertLineNo(str,5); //=> '5: Some line to be numbered'
```

If the method name is equal, you can have the best of both worlds:

```
function insrtNr(str,nr){ return (nr||1) + ': ' + str || this;};
String.insertLineNr = insrtNr;
String.prototype.insertLineNr = insrtNr;
```